# Is there a way to set a beforeFilter method for controller in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to call a method to perform some actions before every action in the CodeIgniter controllers, similar to CakePHP [Controller::beforeFilter](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html#Cake%5CController%5CController::beforeFilter%20Controller::beforeFilter) method.

PD: I'm using Codeigniter-2.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?  Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: Yes. I tried, with hooks, but I had no idea about the corresponding CI hook.

I solved already testing and testing. I was looking for examples of use, because documentation is very poor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is.

Its called **Hooks**

See here for [CI-2](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/hooks.html)

See here for [CI-3](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html)

Comment: Yes. I tried with hooks, but I had no idea about the corresponding CI hook.

I solved already testing and testing. I was looking for examples of use, because documentation is very poor.

Comment: I solved using CodeIgniter hooks and MY_Controller:

https://gist.github.com/nelson6e65/5e3c4b79bd2989239ec2